# React native square logo not showing perfect

Tags: android, react-native

See the `10er App logo`, I want it tobe in full size like other logos.

I created logo icons from https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher,

After generating it looks good but in device, it won't.

please help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Android icons require five separate sizes for different screen pixel densities. Icons for lower resolution are created automatically from the baseline.
check this icon reference chart:
[Android Icon Reference Chart](https://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/)

Comment: 48 × 48 (mdpi),
72 × 72 (hdpi),
96 × 96 (xhdpi),
144 × 144 (xxhdpi),
192 × 192 (xxxhdpi)

I have manually resize images but still  same